# foursquare check who is checked

Tags: api, foursquare

How i can check who was in venue? Do i need to be owner?

In https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/id

Provides a count of how many people are at a given venue. If the request is user authenticated, also returns a list of the users there, friends-first.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this yourself: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3

In the response there is a "hereNow" field that shows two groups: friends who are here now, and anyone else who is here now. You do not need to be the owner to see this information.

Note that if you make the request without being authenticated (e.g., https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3 without the ?oauth_token= ) then the request will fail, so you do need to be acting on the part of a user, but any user will do.